Unable to open browser in non-incognito in Playwright
I tried this but it's not opening a browser.
 Path userDataDir = Path.of("myPath");
 BrowserContext BrowserContext = playwright.chromium().launchPersistentContext(userDataDir);
 page = Browser.newPage();
 page.navigate(url)

I am using playwright Java using IntelliJ IDEA

Incognito mode is when you use code as in this link:
https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context

Playwright allows creating "incognito" browser contexts with Browser.newContext() method. "Incognito" browser contexts don't write any browsing data to disk.

If you want to open a browser and see it, and also wait till you explicitly close it, then use this code:
  try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
        Browser browser = playwright.webkit().launch(
                new BrowserType
                        .LaunchOptions()
                        .setHeadless(false) // Makes browser visible
        );

        Page page = browser.newPage();

        // This will create a new context - meaning a browser will be in incognito mode
        //BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
        //Page page = context.newPage();

        page.navigate("http://playwright.dev");

        page.waitForClose(() -> {});
    }

